# Insert into array random words on random positions

Tags: php, arrays, random

Is there any why to insert into an array that whas maked from a big text (1000k+ words(1 row no `\n` or `\r`)) using `preg_split("/\s/", $str);` in random position another array that contains on key the specific word and the value how many times ?

I need to declare a wordspacing betwen the text words and the words that need to be inserted.

An example to understand what i have been saying:
This is the text before adding:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Lorem
    [1] => ipsum
    [2] => dolor
    [3] => sit
    [4] => amet,
    [5] => consectetur
    [6] => adipisicing
    [7] => elit,
    [8] => sed
    [9] => do
    [10] => eiusmod
    [11] => temporincididunt
    [12] => ut
    [13] => labore
    [14] => et
 )
```

This are the words:

```
Array
(
    [word1] => 2 // like i sayed word1 is the word that needs inserted and 2 is how many times
    [word2] => 3 // like i sayed word2 is the word that needs inserted and 3 is how many times
)
```

This is the text after added:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Lorem
    [1] => word2
    [2] => ipsum
    [3] => dolor
    [4] => sit
    [5] => word1
    [6] => amet,
    [7] => consectetur
    [8] => adipisicing
    [9] => elit,
    [10] => word1
    [11] => sed
    [12] => do
    [13] => eiusmod
    [14] => word2
    [15] => temporincididunt
    [16] => ut
    [17] => labore
    [18] => word2
    [19] => et
 )
```

Comment: `array_splice()` with a random position and a 0 length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($newWords as $newWord => $count) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
        array_splice($allWords, mt_rand(0, count($allWords)-1), 0, $newWord);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly what you need,
you can use array_count_values after split the text:

```
$splitResult = array("Lorem","word2","ipsum","dolor","sit","word1","amet","word1");

$newArray = array_count_values($splitResult);
```

now, the array key is the word and the array value is the number of words in your text:

```
foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) {
        echo "$key - <strong>$value</strong> <br />"; 
}
```

I hope you helpful

Comment: Ok it's a good ideea, but i have another problem how can i detect who many times to insert and what i forget to type to pre-declare a word spacing betwen keywords (word1,word2). I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

simple use `array_count_values`

http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-count-values.php

```
$array = array("foo","bar","foo","baz","foo","baz");
$counts = array_count_values($array);

print_r($counts);
Array
(
    [foo] => 3
    [bar] => 1
    [baz] => 2
)
```